# How to assign values to Multidimentional Arrays In Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, string

Looking at a few articles on here i learned that To declare a 2D array in android studio you must do something like

```
String[][] stations=new String[1][10];
```

And to insert data into the 2D array i just created I Did This

```
stations[1][0]= "New York";
stations[2][0]= "Boston";
stations[3][0]= "Las Vegas";
stations[4][0]= "Miami";
stations[5][0]= "Chicago";
stations[6][0]= "New England";
stations[7][0]= "Detroit";
stations[8][0]= "Michigan";
stations[9][0]= "Austin";
```

When I run this i get the error message

```
Unfortunately DB Has Stopped
```

And so I decided to comment out the code where I coped the strings into the arrays and the app ran perfectly. 
What am i doing wrong with these assignment operations?

Heres my source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button trainSearch;
String[][] stations=new String[1][10];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    trainSearch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    trainSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search();

        }
    });

}

public void search()
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "function called Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    /*stations[1][0]= "New York";
    stations[2][0]= "Boston";
    stations[3][0]= "Las Vegas";
    stations[4][0]= "Miami";
    stations[5][0]= "Chicago";
    stations[6][0]= "New England";
    stations[7][0]= "Detroit";
    stations[8][0]= "Michigan";
    stations[9][0]= "Austin";*/
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
    try{
        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stations ("
                + "Station_name VARCHAR);";
        db.execSQL(query);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        /*int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            query = "INSERT or replace INTO stations (Station_name) VALUES(" + stations[0][i] + ");";
            db.execSQL(query);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added Staation"+stations[0][i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An Error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void calladminactivity(View v)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, adminlogin.class));

}
}
```

Comment: You've got the indexes switched. You're initializing the first one to size 1, but trying to access elements 1-9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new String[1][10]` means you have an array with one item, and this item has an array of 10 items.

In your code you were trying to access items that do no exist - stations[1], stations[2] etc. Only stations[0] exists.

The correct code will be:

```
stations[0][1]= "New York";
stations[0][2]= "Boston";
...
```

Comment: By the way, `new String[1][10]` makes **no sense** at all: it's the same as declaring `new String[10]` (which is also **easier to manage**).

Comment: You are absolutely right - my assumption was that he is going to keep working on the code, as he said he needs multi-dimensional array. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yes, and you got my +1 for your answer. I was addressing the OP. ;)